# AngularJS: var in resolve is not injected in controller (unknown provider)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

An unknown provider error of var "frameworks" appears in resolve, what is wrong? thanks! 
FrameworkService.loadFrameworks() return a JSON array from REST Service.

**app.js**

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl : "views/admin.html",
    controller : "FrameworkController",
     resolve : {
        frameworks : function(FrameworkService) {
            return FrameworkService.loadFrameworks();
        }
    }
});
```

**FrameworkController.js**

```
angular.module('app.controllers', []).controller(
    'FrameworkController',
    [ '$scope', 'FrameworkService', 'frameworks',
            function($scope, frameworks) {
                $scope.frameworks = frameworks;
            } ]);
```

**ERROR**

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: frameworksProvider <- frameworks
```

**EDIT**

The code showed here it's ok! The problem was in the FrameworkService, that do an asynchronous http request, so var frameworks wasn't injected.

Comment: your controller function signature should be with all the parameters defined in inline definition: $scope, FrameworkService, frameworks. In your case I think you could delete FrameworkService inline definition

Comment: I removed FrameworkService of the definition but the same error appears. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a frameworks provider in your module, so the injector can't give you one. You need to create one be it a service, factory, etc. Depending on what you want.

Comment: I thought that "frameworks" var was injected in the controller automatically. I saw that in one tutorial.